# Bootstrap 3 modal and Backbone.js View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, view, modal-dialog

My Bootstrap modal, called from Backbone View keeps propagating events. When I fetch model from db, it's view is displayed on page. After clicking a delete button, a modal pops up prompting for confirmation or cancel. I have setted up that letter "P" is logged every time cancel is clicked. I got this:

```
First modal call->First cancel click: P
Second modal call->Second cancel click: 2P
Third modal call-> Third cancel click: 3P
Fourth modal call-> Fourth cancel click: 5P
```

My code:

```
App.Views.Objava = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "objava-single",

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    events: {
        'click #delete-objava': 'izbrisiObjavu',
        'click .glyphicon-paperclip': 'javnoObjavi',
        'click .glyphicon-eye-close': 'javnoPonistiObjavu'
    },
    remove: function () {
        this.$el.remove();
    },
    izbrisiObjavu: function (event) {
        var model = this.model;
        $(".modal-obrisi").modal();
        $(".dugme-obrisi").on("click", function () {
            model.destroy({
                success: function () {
                    $(".modal-obrisi").modal("hide");
                    $('.modal-obrisi').data('modal', null);
                },
                error: function () {}
            });
        });
        $('.modal-obrisi').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
            console.log("P");
        });
    }
});
```

Help me to see how to prevent that propagation.

Comment: Not sure but have you tried [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation)

Comment: Yes, no result. My lack of knowldge and expirience. I have also try to add in hidden event callback:  $(this).data("bs.modal", null); Also no result. Without modal everything works great. I need to destroy modal compleatly , but it wont :/